# How can I install dependency files without admin privileges?

Tags: command-line, bypass

i’m trying to install the game league of legends which has worked fine so far. if i run as administrator, it doesn’t necessarily ask for the admin password, just the password i use to log into the computer. after i do that it runs the game and stuff but this error keeps telling me i need to install the dependency update, but can’t for whatever reason. when i went to league support it said it is probably because i have no admin rights on my computer, which i do not. is there any way i can fix this? all existing tutorials are from years ago and aren’t valid for the version i’m installing now. how can i download the dependencies without admin privileges?

Comment: You should edit your question and provide the exact error you have received

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install the app without Admin privileges. You cannot just go around it. So ask the person who has Admin credentials to install the game for you.